# Confusión clases abstractas, herencia y atributos en java

Tags: java, poo, herencia, clase-abstracta

Mi duda es cómo implementar métodos concretos de una clase que hereda de otra abstracta. Como veréis en mi código, puedo acceder a métodos de la clase padre, pero no de la clase hija.

También quiero saber si está bien implementado el override del atributo descripción o hay alguna forma más correcta o eficiente de hacerlo. Muchas gracias.

```
package clasesabstractas;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClasesAbstractas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Persona p1 = new Alumno("Primero","Mariano");

        p1.dameDescripcion();

        System.out.println(p1.getDescripcion());

        System.out.println(p1.getCurso());
    }

}
```

---

```
package clasesabstractas;

public abstract class Persona {
    private String Nombre;
    protected String Descripcion;

    public Persona(String Nombre) {
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
    }

    public abstract void dameDescripcion();

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String Nombre) {
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return Descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String Descripcion) {
        this.Descripcion = Descripcion;
    }

}
```

---

```
package clasesabstractas;

public class Alumno extends Persona {
    private String Curso;

    public Alumno(String Curso, String Nombre) {
        super(Nombre);
        this.Curso = Curso;
    }

    @Override
    public void dameDescripcion(){
        super.Descripcion="Esto es un alumno.";
    }

    public String getCurso() {
        return Curso;
    }

    public void setCurso(String Curso) {
        this.Curso = Curso;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola Marcos, bienvenido. Puedes cambiar las fotos por texto? Para formatearlo en el editor lo seleccionas todo y pulsas `ctrl+k` o el icono `{}`. Si no te sale, te edito yo la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabía lo de ctrl + k. Acabo de editarlo.

Comment: De nada. Recuerda pasar por el [tour] y [ask] para aprender como funciona este sitio. Como comentario, las variables van en minuscula y las clases en mayuscula. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La implementación de la clase `Alumno` heredando de la clase abstracta `Persona` es correcta y el método está correctamente sobrescrito.

Un par de cosillas solo:

1- **No puedes hacer uso de métodos de la clase hija cuando la instancia es del tipo padre**. Sólo puedes usar los métodos que conoce la clase padre. Por tanto, la siguiente sentencia dará error:

```
System.out.println(p1.getCurso());
```

Ya que **getCurso** existe en la clase hija `Alumno` pero no en la clase `Persona` y, **p1**, es un objeto de tipo `Persona`.

Podrías hacerlo de este modo si sabes con seguridad que el objeto **p1** es realmente de tipo `Alumno`:

```
try {
    Alumno a1 = (Alumno) p1;
    System.out.println(a1.getCurso());
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    // Si no es de la clase Alumno da un error de casting...
}
```

2- No hace falta hacer uso de `super.` para usar un atributo heredado de la clase padre, ya que este forma parte directamente de la clase hija:

```
super.Descripcion="Esto es un alumno.";
```