# error : Personal is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, clase-abstracta

hasta el ultimo en p = new Personal me da el error: Personal is abstract; cannot be instantiated
Tambien aqui agregue la clase Personal y segun yo si lo puse como metodo abstracto

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PruebaAdmonPersonal {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
      int opc, id, horasContrato, celda, dato, resp;
      String nombre, fechaNac, puesto;
      char  sexo;
      AdmonPersonal ap = new AdmonPersonal();
      Personal p;
      
        do{
        
         System.out.println("\nCATALGO DE MA");
         System.out.println("[1] ALTAS");
         System.out.println("[2] CONSULTA INDIVIDUAL");
         System.out.println("[3] CONSULTA GENERAL");
         System.out.println("[4] MODIFICACIONES");
         System.out.println("[5] BAJAS");
         System.out.println("[6] FINALIZAR");
         System.out.println("¿Opcion deseada? [1-6]: ");
         opc = leer.nextInt();
         switch(opc) {
            case 1: //ALTAS
                if(ap.hayEspacio()) {
                   System.out.print("ingrese el id del maestro a dar de alta");
                   id= leer.nextInt();
                   if(ap.validarId(id)) {
                     celda = ap.busqueda(id);
                     if(celda == -1) {
                     leer.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Id-----------: ");
                        id = leer.nextInt();
                        
                        System.out.print("Nombre-----------: ");
                        nombre = leer.nextLine();
                        
                        System.out.print("Sexo (H,M)-----------: ");
                        sexo = leer.nextLine().charAt(0);
                       
                        System.out.print("Fecha de  nacimiento(dd-mm-aaaa)-------: ");
                        fechaNac= leer.nextLine();
                        p = new Personal (id, nombre, sexo, fechaNac);//Personal is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

Clase Personal

```
public abstract class Personal {
   private int id;
   private String nombre;
   private char sexo;
   private String fechaNac;
   
   public Personal (int id, String nombre, char sexo, String fechaNac) {
      this.id = id;
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.sexo = sexo;
      this.fechaNac = fechaNac;
     }
     
     public int getid(){
      return id;
     }
     
     public String getNombre(){
      return nombre;
     }
     
     public char getSexo(){
      return sexo;
     }
     
     public String getFechaNac(){
      return fechaNac;
     }
      public void setId(int id) {
         this.id = id;
     }
     public void setNombre(String nombre) {
         this.nombre = nombre;
     }
     
     public void setSexo(char sexo) {
         this.sexo = sexo;
     }
      public void setFechaNac(String fechaNac) {
         this.fechaNac= fechaNac;
     }
     public abstract float calcularSalario();
     
 }
```

Comment: Las clases abstractas no pueden ser instanciadas como clases, para ello deberías crear una clase que herede esa clase abstracta y definir los métodos abstractos

Comment: Si quieres tengo [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/485506/cu%c3%a1ndo-debo-usar-herencia-interface-o-una-clase-abstracta/485516#485516) que explica un poco los temas de POO. Pero como recomendación **importante** es que investigaras por tu cuenta el uso de clases abstractas en Java. Te dejo el [tutorial de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) como referencia

Comment: AdmonPersonal(); esta clase deberia tener el metodo public float calcularSalario() definida

Comment: En este enlace se comenta tu mismo problema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62211/confusi%C3%B3n-clases-abstractas-herencia-y-atributos-en-java Un saludo!